# Can we apply a for loop on select sql statement?

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a SQL table with 150+ columns and I want to apply on them an aggregation function when selecting values but I don't to list all column names by hand. Instead I want to use a for loop through the column names of the table.

I want to do something like this:

```sql
SELECT
  AGREEMENT_NO,
  COUNT(DISTINCT column) FOR column LOOP columns -- Instead of 150+ lines of count
WHERE ...
GROUP BY AGREEMENT_NO
```

Does anyone know if it's possible to do it in SQL and if yes how?

Comment: You may do this in excel and paste generated query. I do not really know about listed DBMSes, but I've never heard of such features in any SQL implementation

Comment: In Snowflake, you could use a Javascript Stored Procedure to generate the SQL statement based on information_schema.columns data.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by dynamic query.

1. Take every column of a table by in temporary table by Information_Schema.columns.
2. Take a while loop for temporary table for all row.
3. Write dynamic query and concat column name for your requirement.
4. Execute the query. Eg. Exec("Query" / variable).

This will give you exact result.